# Output format in MatrixForm

Tags: output-formatting

I have a correlation matrix, which I want to display in the following format:

- 2 decimal places (e.g., -0.56)
- number signs "+" and "-" (e.g., +0.76 or -0.34)

I've tried many different things, but I had no success so far... 
The code I'm using to generate the data is:

```
randomWalk[x_] := Accumulate[Prepend[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], 0]]
exchange = Table[Subscript[asset, i] = randomWalk[500], {i, 1, 5}];
```

Now the code I'm using to generate the correlation matrix:

```
N[Correlation[Transpose[exchange][[1 ;; 500, All]]], 2]//MatrixForm
```

However, the numbers generated are displayed with `$MachinePrecision`, and not 2 decimal places (although I've used `N[#,2]`). I've tried another code:

```
MatrixForm[Round[Correlation[Transpose[exchange][[1 ;; 500, All]]], 0.01]]
```

In this case I get the correlation matrix with 2 decimal places, but it's still missing the "+" signal before the number. So I've tried this last code:

```
NumberForm[Round[Correlation[Transpose[exchange][[1 ;; 500, All]]], 0.01],NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}]//MatrixForm
```

In this last case I get the numbers correctly formatted, but I'm not able to put them in `MatrixForm`. Can someone give me a hint to solve this?

Comment: Why not NumberForm[MatrixForm[Round[...,NumbersSigns->{"-","+"}]?

Comment: @ andre Thanks A LOT !!! It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to wrap NumberForm around MatrixForm :

`NumberForm[MatrixForm[Round[...,NumbersSigns->{"-","+"}]` does the job

Answer (score 5):

Of course there are many ways of doing this. Here's one:

```
mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}]
Table[NumberForm[mat[[i, j]], {3, 2}, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}], 
     {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

You get:

[image]

Comment: Imagine you have `mat` defined... try to use: `NumberForm[mat, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}] // TableForm`. It doesn't work...

Comment: what's wrong with the output of the above, either Table or Map?

Comment: You've generated numbers **with** 2 decimal places... try something with `$MachinePrecision`...

Comment: mat has full real precision, it's the argument {3,2} that does the truncating to 3 significant digits plus two to the right of the decimal place.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is: I'm already using `mat[[1 ;; 500, All]]` inside a `DynamicModule` environment... so, I can't use `Table[mat[[i,j]],{i,1,4},{j,1,4}]`...

Comment: @RodLm What would be the problem there? You understand bill's matrix is just an example, right? We wouldn't like to display a 500x5 matrix here just to be closer to your matrix

Comment: Yes, I understand that perfectly... the problem, as said, is: I'm running `exchange[[1 ;; 500, All]]` inside a `DynamicModule` environment, but instead of `500` I have `n++` (this means I compute my correlation matrix dinamically). So, how could I use `Table` together with `DynamicModule`, once I use `mat[[1;; n++,All]]`? As far as I have tried, its not possible to use `Table[NumberForm[mat[[i, j]][[1;;n++, All]], {3, 3},NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}], {i,1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}] // MatrixForm`...

Comment: @andre Thanks for the solution... somehow `MatrixForm` outside `NumberForm` doesn't work... We just need to put it inside `NumberForm`, as he suggested:  `NumberForm[MatrixForm[Round[...,NumberSigns->{"-","+"}]`...